# Scala immutable array with cheap slicing

Tags: scala, collections

I'm looking for a collection that wraps a regular array and supports low cost `tail`, `slice`, `take`... operations.

It's just a data structure that stores an array, start index and end index. Like Java strings.
Of course it's not a big deal to implement it by myself but I expect that it should have been done already.

Both `WrappedArray` and `scalaz.ImmutableArray` are not structure-sharing.

Comment: What's wrong with [List](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)? Performance?

Comment: Same things that are wrong with list compared to a regular array: performance of random access, performance of iteration, memory footprint. 
Also if I get an array from a third-party api I need first to convert it into list.

Comment: The problem with Arrays, is that, unlike Strings, they _are mutable_. I doubt very much there is a library structure sharing them therefore. And if there is one, it's probably really buggy

Comment: @Dima it's not a big problem. The data structure is effectively immutable under assumption that nobody is subtly modifying this array from the outside. No linear types :( . Also the array could be cloned once in the constructor.

Comment: If nobody modifies it, _any_ datastructure is "effectively immutable" by that logic. :)
For the rest of us, _immutable_ means "impossible" to modify, not just that "nobody wants to modify it". By that definition, arrays are mutable, and a library implementing structure sharing over them would be horribly broken.
Sure, it can be cloned ... that's essentially what `WrappedArray` implementation does.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear what I mean. 1) `WrappedArray.slice` implementation creates new array every time. And it couldn't be changed since it exposes api to modify it.

Comment: 2) I agree that `new MyImmutableArray(arr)` must clone the array (default safe behavior). But `MyMutableArray.unsafeWrap(arr)` would be also useful. If I can e.g. guarantee that I was the only holder of the reference to `arr` then after wrapping it no one else can modify it and arr is effectively immutable. You can say that it is a lie but for rest of us who haven't yet got a job in  Haskell purity-by-convention as a thing :) Same as non-nullability-by-convention.

Comment: I am not saying it's not useful, just that it is a clumsy, and would make for a bad public API, so, it is not there. It's not hard to implement it on your own if you like it, I am just explaining why it is not a part of any good scala libraries.

Comment: And yes, nullability is ugly. I think, it is a design flaw in scala, that you can assign a null to any reference.